# Reflection without a Getter/Setter?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties, runtime

If I declare the following in my class:

```
private int? MyID = null;
```

And then attempt to access it via reflection, it won't be able to find it.  What I mean by that is, the below will set gProp to null:

```
gType = refObj.GetType();
gProp = gType.GetProperty(PropertyName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
```

However, it will work fine if I instead declare it as:

```
private int? MyID { get; set; }
```

This isn't at all surprising to me as I already knew this to be the case.  However, I wanted to confirm; is there anyway to make the first declaration work with reflection, or do I have provide a Getter/Setter in order for reflection to work?

Thanks!

Comment: That's what I was looking for!  Was hoping that existed.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `GetField` method (instead of `GetProperty`) for Fields.

> **Type.GetFields Method**
>   Searches for the specified field, using the specified binding constraints.

#### Sample

```
// your instance
MyObject instance = new MyObject();
// get type information
Type myType = typeof(MyObject);
// get field information
FieldInfo fieldInfo = myType.GetField("MyID");
// set some value
fieldInfo.SetValue(instance, 123);
// get field value
var value = fieldInfo.GetValue(instance);
// value is 123
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - Type.GetField Method (String, BindingFlags)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e.aspx)
- [MSDN - SetField Method (String, BindingFlags, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244028%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I was using PropertyInfo, since I was calling GetProperty before, so it was helpful.

Answer (score 9):

It is a field, not a property, so it won't be returned by `GetProperty`. You need to use `GetField` method.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between

```
private int? MyID = null;
```

and

```
private int? MyID { get; set; }
```

The first is a [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx), and the second is a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

You should use the [`Type.GetField()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e.aspx) method when trying to find a field via reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a property for accessing the variables in the class. So you manually create a property like

```
private int? MyID { get { return _myID;} }
```

The below code works, since it is Auto property in c#

```
private int? MyID { get; set; }
```

Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My logic states the first is a simple variable, the second is a property, because it has the get/set, so for "GetProperty" to work, it needs to be a property. If you wanted a variable, you need the GetField