# Inherit Properties of Entity class into another

Tags: c#

I have Employee Entity as

```
public class Employee
{
    public Employee();

    public int BossId { get; }
    public int BossUserId { get; }
    public string CostCentre { get; }
    public int CostCentreId { get; }
    public string Department { get; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; }
    public string Designation { get; }
    public int DesignationId { get; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string FullName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
    public string LoginId { get; }
    public int UserId { get; }

    public override string ToString();
}
```

I want to use all these properties in another entity and assign values to them.

My another entity is as

```
public class UserRoles
{
    public UserRoles()
    {
    }

    public int UserRoleId { get; set; }
    public long EmpUserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedOn { get; set; }
    public long AddedBy { get; set; }
    public long ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOnd { get; set; }
  }
```

If i create property of Employee class, I am not able to assign values to it. And i can not change Employee class as it is in some dll.

Is there any way i can override it or inherit and assign values to these properties?

Comment: Inherit from Employee? `public class UserRoles : Employee`. You will have all properties, but that will be odd - user roles is not employee. Btw I don't understand why you can't use property of `Employee` type

Comment: yes but i can not assign values to properties of Employee

Comment: I am not using property of Employee type because I want properties of UserRole also

Comment: Why you can't assign values to properties of Employee? I don't see any reason for that

Comment: Because there's no setter.

Comment: @X.L.Ant ah, my bad. Looks like Employee is a Value Object. Properties should not be changed by design. Question still unclear

Answer (score 1):

You could encapsulate the Employee class with your own class EmployeeWrapper, and in EmployeeWrapper put logic that uses reflection to set properties of the Employee class as described in [Reflection without a Getter/Setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478047/reflection-without-a-getter-setter).

Then you use your EmployeeWrapper and pass parameters through its constructor for example, or just setting its properties, and in the back it uses reflection to set the properties of the actual Employee instance.